# Permissions Failure on Facebook Messenger Bot with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, rubygems, bots, messenger

I built a Facebook Messenger bot using the [Facebook Messenger Gem](https://github.com/jgorset/facebook-messenger) a couple of months ago for a project going live soon, and when going to update the chatbot I've gotten permissions errors that I have never gotten and it's been a couple of months since touching the code. Perhaps could be Facebook's SDK or updates to the Gem? Unsure, but please have a look and let me know if you know of a potential solution.

I've started a completely new bot using this [create messenger bot with rails tutorial](https://chatbotslife.com/create-a-facebook-messenger-bot-with-ruby-on-rails-4ffd8b851135) just to see if it was something with my code or env variables but sure enough, it yields the same error even on a completely new project.

So, every time I try to run my rails server, or any rails command for that matter it will either yield this error or an error about an active access token. I've even tested hardcoding the token in to see if it was an issue reading env variables but was still yielding permissions error.

```
/Users/elijohnston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/facebook-messenger-1.1.1/lib/facebook/messenger/subscriptions.rb:73:in 'raise_errors': (#100) No enough permission to subscribe one or more of fields you specified (Facebook::Messenger::Subscriptions::Error)
```

When I comment out my bot code in `app/bot/listen.rb` then I can launch the rails server, but then once I try to post a message (`/POST`) to bot on Messenger, I get a similar message in my terminal server logs.

```
Started GET "/bot?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=1798107466&hub.verify_token=anythingiwant" for 2a03:2880:11ff:d::face:b00c at 2018-09-23 09:05:23 +0800
Cannot render console from 2a03:2880:11ff:d::face:b00c! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Started POST "/bot" for 2a03:2880:40ff:3::face:b00c at 2018-09-23 09:10:12 +0800
Cannot render console from 2a03:2880:40ff:3::face:b00c! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255

Facebook::Messenger::Subscriptions::Error ((#100) No enough permission to subscribe one or more of fields you specified):

app/bot/listen.rb:4:in `<main>'
config/initializers/facebook_messenger.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
config/initializers/facebook_messenger.rb:5:in `each'
config/initializers/facebook_messenger.rb:5:in `block in <main>'
config/initializers/facebook_messenger.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
Started POST "/bot" for 2a03:2880:40ff::face:b00c at 2018-09-23 09:10:26 +0800
Cannot render console from 2a03:2880:40ff::face:b00c! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Ignoring message (no hook registered)
```

This problem began a month ago, but before that was not giving any issues. Any help would be appreciated!